# Upcoming events from specific groups using Venti

Tags: plugin-ventievents

I'm new to both Craft and Venti so apologies if this is quite basic.

I've got multiple groups setup using Venti and multiple events within these groups.

On the client side I just want to display the 5 upcoming events from a specific group. Anyone know the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 3):

After looking at this for over an hour I've literally figured it out. Just in case others need it:

```
craft.venti.events.group('handle').limit(5)
```

So easy!